# Autohotkey: How to read a variable from a string

Tags: autohotkey

I am making a code so that I can paste text down from a menu, this is the code I have at the moment:

```
Lolita := "hi, My name is Lolita"

    Menu, Submenu1, Add, Lolita, MenuHandler

    Menu, Submenu2, Add, Royalty, MenuHandler

Menu, MyMenu, Add, Male, :Submenu1
Menu, MyMenu, Add, Female, :Submenu2

MenuHandler:
    MyVar := A_ThisMenuItem
    send %MyVar%
return

RButton & LControl::Menu, MyMenu, Show
```

I get the name Lolita in MyVar or A_ThisMenuItem.
I want to send the value of the variable at the top of the file.
I just dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the variable in an expression.
Thus the contents of the expanded variable will be treated as a variable itself.

```
MyVar := %A_ThisMenuItem%
```

Comment: If I change this it gives me an error: this dynamic variable is blank. If this variable was not intended to be dynamic, remove the % symbols from it.. NEVERMIND, it does not stop it all, thank you it worked